# Initializing a fixed length 2d list and populating without external library in python

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, syntax

I am trying to initialize an n by n list and then populate it by iterating through each row and column, but it doesn't work because say `n = 2`, `[[None, None], [None, None]]` does not get populated the same way as `[[None] * 2] * 2`.

For example:

```
n = 2 # int(input())
var_array = [[None] * n] * n
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        var_array[i][j] = (i, j)
        for v in var_array:
            print(v)
print(var_array)
```

Output:
`[[(1, 0), (1, 1)], [(1, 0), (1, 1)]]`
And that is because it populates both rows at col j instead of only row i:

```
>>> [[None, None], [None, None]] == [[None] * 2] * 2
True
>>> var1 = [[None, None], [None, None]]
>>> var2 = [[None] * 2] * 2
>>> var1[0][0] = 5
>>> var1
[[5, None], [None, None]]
>>> var2[0][0] = 5
>>> var2
[[5, None], [5, None]]
```

p.s. I am aware of better ways of populating an n by n list, but I need to do it this way  - populate an already initialized 2d n by n list - to optimize a part of another program

Comment: You want `[[None]*n for _ in range(n)]` or `[[None for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  right, I tried [[None] * n] * n instead because I thought it is faster especially for really large n, but apparently it doesn't work

Comment: It's faster *precisely because* of the behavior you are seeing, it doesn't create new inner list objects, it simply puts multiple references to the same list in the outer list. That is *always* how `n*[x]` works. EDIT: and because it does the looping in C, essentialyl pre-allocating the buffer and simply putting PyObject pointers in the buffer using a c-level loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ahh that makes sense, so I guess there is no more optimal way to initialize that. Thank you for the explanation.